# Can't connect to WiFi, nor wifi.sta.getap() doesn't work

Tags: lua, wifi, esp8266

I have a problem with my ESP-201 module(s). I had some working program, but now, when I tried to run it, it can't connect to WiFi. I've already tried 4 more ESP-201 modules and I've discovered, that what more, nor the `wifi.sta.getap()` function doesn't work. It simply does nothing.

```
ssid = 'EMtest'
function check(t)
  for k,v in pairs(t) do
    if k == ssid then
      print("Network was found!")
    return end
  end
  print("Network was not found!")
end
tmr.alarm(0, 5000, 1, function() wifi.sta.getap(check) end)
```

Can it be caused by broken modules? I've really tried it on 5 modules!
When I try it on my old code, it returns "reason 201 NO_AP_FOUND".
Resoldering for using inner antenna didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

So, it's solved, it was caused by incompatible versions of new ESP - 201s' SDK. My firmware was build on 1.4.5 SDK, and there was 2.1.0 in ESP. So i downloaded new firware and `ESP_init_data`, and it works.